# perl quick sort

Tags: perl, sorting

Is there a way to do very quick sort in perl? Like I have a very large hash, probably with 100 million keys there. It is very inefficient to do `foreach my $x (sort {$a cmp $b} keys %myhash){DO SOMETHING}` when I test. Wondering if I can first copy out all keys to a array and use a quick sort to it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `sort {$a cmp $b} %myhash` will try to sort *both the keys and values* of your hash, which I'm certain is not what you're trying to do.

Comment: 100 million keys in a hash (in memory) sounds like you should be considering something else than perl. Database?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, yes that's a typo I mean sort{$a cmp $b} keys %myhash

Comment: OK, well it takes a long time to sort 100 million of anything.  Generally the command-line `sort` is very well-optimised and knows how to break up datasets too large to sort in memory efficiently, so it can be faster to write the data out, run `sort` on it, and then read it back.

Comment: Why do you need all 100 million keys sorted in "ASCII-betical" order?  Is it possible you are really only interested in a subset of those 100 million keys?  ...or in partitioning them?  And why not a more useful order?

Comment: You might consider using an ordered datastructure and inserting the keys in sorted order rather than sorting them later. With a Red-Black tree, an inserting will be O(log N), followed by a linear walk to get all the elements. Sorting afterwords will usually be around O(n*log(n)), depending on the algorithm and data.

Comment: @frezik: What happens when you do an O(log N) operation N times? ;)

Comment: I suggest that you explain what you are trying to do.  It may be that sorting is not the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't want to put the hash in a list context, because you do not want the values sorted with the keys. Instead, *yes* you want to sort the keys:

```
my @ordered_keys = sort { $a cmp $b } keys %hash;
```

However, if you wanted to deal with the *values* in that way, you could do this:

```
my @ordered_values = @hash{ sort { $a cmp $b } keys %hash };
```

This uses a ["hash slice"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

But in this fashion, you could do the following:

```
foreach my $value ( @hash{ sort { $a cmp $b } keys %hash } ) { 
    # key? What key?
    do_something_with_hash_value( $value );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Say sorting 100 strings takes 10μs (10 millionth of a second). Would you consider that fast? Probably. That's roughly what my machine does.

If so, you should consider 41s fast for 100,000,000 strings!

Here's why.

You're not sorting 100 strings; you're sorting 1,000,000 times more string. But sorting isn't linear. The best sorting algorithms are O(N log N). Assuming that's tightly bound, that means

- Sorting 100 strings is going to take $overhead + 100 * log2(100) * $time_per_operation.
- Sorting 100,000,000 keys is going to take $overhead + 1,000,000 * log2(1,000,000) * $time_per_operation.

Assuming negligible overheard, that means sorting 100,000,000 strings will take 4,100,000 times longer than sorting 100 strings.

So if you consider 10μs fast for 100 strings, you should consider 41s fast for 100,000,000 strings.

What kind of numbers are you getting?